# Get a value from Repeater in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="EntityDataSourceTeklifler">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="panel panel-primary">
               <div class="panel-body">
                    <strong>Teklif Kodu:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifId") %><br />
                    <strong>Teklif Tarihi:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTarih") %><br />
                    <strong>Teklifi Hazırlayan:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Name") %>&nbsp;<%#Eval("Surname") %><br />
                    <strong>Firma Adı:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("FirmaAdi") %><br />
                    <strong>Sipariş:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("FUrunId") %><br />
                    <strong>Teklif Tutarı:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifTutar") %><br />
               </div>
          </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

As you can see I have a `Repeater` and it displays my data without a problem. I need to access `TeklifId`s in code-behind. I am going to make something like:

```
if(TeklifId == 1)
{
  //do something
}
else if(TeklifId == 2)
{
  //do something else
}
```

And to do this, I need to get all `TeklifId` while it is adding to the `Repeater`.

Comment: Longe time since I was in Webforms but I think there was something called DataContext for these things.

Comment: @KorayDurudogan - Have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ideally you should include the data withing some ASP.NET controls like `Label, Textbox` control within `ItemTemplate` tag because it is easy to work with them. But I am not sure why you are adding the normal html tags directly.

Anyways, to find the value you will have to find it within the `ItemDataBound` control of repeater control but for that you will have to make the `strong` tag a server control by adding `runat="server"` attrribute like this:-

```
<strong id="TeklifId" runat="server">Teklif Kodu:</strong>&nbsp;<%#Eval("TeklifId") %>
```

Then, add the ItemDataBound event in your repeatre control like this:-

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand"
```

Finally in the code behind you can find the value like this:-

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || 
       e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
       HtmlGenericControl TeklifId = e.Item.FindControl("TeklifId") as HtmlGenericControl;
       string TeklifId = TeklifId.InnerText;  //value here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Place `TeklifId` in a `Label` control so that you can use `ID` and `FindControl` to get the values like this:

```
<asp:Label ID="TeklifId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("TeklifId") %>'></asp:Label>
```

And then:

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in Repeater1.Items)
{
     var TeklifId = (Label)item.FindControl("TeklifId");
     if (TeklifId == 1)
     {
         //do something
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeater Code :

```
<td>
   <span runat="server" id="lbBranchname" style="font-style:italic;"><%# Eval("branchname")%></span>
</td>
```

Code behind : rptBranch_ItemCommand

```
HtmlGenericControl lbBranchname = e.Item.FindControl("lbBranchname") as HtmlGenericControl;
BranchName = lbBranchname.InnerText;
```